Publishing a paper written in your free time as an unaffiliated author when you are affiliated
Suppose you are a researcher that works at a university. You produce, during your free time, i.e. outside of work hours, and without any other university colleague's involvement, a paper with your own funds, so there is no university involvement at any stage during the production of this work.
When submitting the results of this research to a conference/journal, is it ok to not include your university affiliation/university email and instead submit it as an independent researcher with your own personal email address. Are there any potential repercussions that could arise from doing this act?
Edit: I am adding this clarification as I may have badly described my situation. So when I say field, I mean in the sense of discipline. As in for instance, image classification and large language models being part of the same field that is machine learning. In my specific case, the work I'm doing at my university is say on image classification. Before I am able to publish said work, I would need to submit it for an internal review process by the industrial partner where the field of activity of this company is in image classification, say, so that they can decide whether or not they will file a patent on the idea. Now, a large language models paper will be completely irrelevant to this said company, but, because of bureaucracy, I would still need to submit this through the review process that could take multiple months before getting the answer that it is irrelevant to them and that I am able to publish it freely. The source of funding for the work on image classification at the university is for a research project on image classification.

Why do think that would be a good idea or a useful approach?

I didn't really suggest it was a good/useful idea, I am only wondering if one was constrained and had to go with this approach, what would be the potential ramifications.

Assuming using a personal computer and only having access to open access journals, without requiring the university credentials to access the literature?

The subject of this paper is unrelated to your academic subject matter?  So you will never (in the future) want it to be considered for academic promotion/tenure?  For example, it is a riské topic (or a political topic) you do not want linked to your academic persona?

yes, for instance ML conference papers are all open access.

@GEdgar The subject of this paper is very much related to my field. And it is not a riske topic.

Then why would you not want the affiliation? I would say trying to avoid affiliation on a regular paper even if you think you did it all in your spare time is just not worth the hassle.

Guessing here ... to make sure patents resulting from the research cannot be claimed by the university?

@MaartenBuis I can't really go too much into the details, but it is mainly related to a a green light which takes multiple months that I need to obtain before I'm able to publish my work, if I have to do this as a researcher affiliated with my university. This has mainly to do with the source of funding (industry).

So this ‘independent’ work is directly related to your field, and you are looking to bypass review by those funding your research/position? What could possibly go wrong?

Sounds like a recipe for a Rube Goldberg machine of Unfortunate Legal Events.

The obvious answer is to ask your boss, if the answer isn’t already clear in your terms of employment or company policy. Perhaps you already know what your boss would say if asked and you are hoping to get a different answer here? Even if we were to give you permission, that wouldn’t hold much water with your boss when they find out. Where I work, the policy is very clear: I need to have any manuscripts approved before submission and I need approval for any outside work.

I think the answer you’re hoping for is not one you’ll get. And are there extenuating circumstances making the few-month delay impractical?

What is your field that you can do this without any University resources? Maths? Theoretical physics? As a computer vision researcher, I don't think I could make a particularly meaningful contribution using only equipment I have personally purchased in my field.

It's in ML but oriented more towards the math aspect.

Is uploading to the arXiv also restricted until the industry partner has reviewed it?

Yes, so essentially any form of dissemination in the public domain that would render a patent application void by this company is not allowed.

Many academic positions do not have set hours and hence the concept of "free time" is sadly not always valid.

"You produce, during your free time, i.e. outside of work hours" Do you actually have and obey work hours in the sense that anything you do between, say, 9 am to 5 pm is "work" and anything you do outside of that timeframe is "not work"? Do you, in a given week, do precisely (e.g.) 40 hours of "work" and not more and not less? If not, you thereby admit that "work hours" are more or less a fiction, so two questions naturally arise, namely (1) what do you actually mean by "outside of work hours", and (2) how can anyone verify that you did this "outside of work hours".

This question belongs into "employment law" as well. There are legal responsibilities that you have to fulfill and they might make your proposed behavior ineffective.

The institution might be able to assert patent rights over any
invention contained in the publication.

You violated an enforceable condition of employment. If you were working at a university, your tenure could be removed. Depending on your country, this can be expressed (sometimes in coded language) in future letters of reference.


Your institution disagrees that your work has nothing to do with your employment and can take action against third party such as asking the publisher to remove your article as it contains trade secrets. (I have seen something like this happening, where USENIX pulled an article for some months because of a (completely fictitious Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) violation.)


How the conference and the people in your field will view your action, assuming you followed your proposal, is also difficult to assess.

You might be seen as dishonest / disloyal employee since you did not approach your institution / boss to ask for guidance. It would seem that you anticipated a negative answer and went ahead anyway. This would influence future employability.

You could be seen as a righteous rebel who prefers science over safety and is willing to cut through bureaucratic red tape.

You could be seen as a loose cannon who cannot be trusted with keeping to procedure.


As an aside, your institution will be important when a decision is made on your paper. Often, there is a double-blind peer review, but a program committee or editor can look at affiliations and notice something off if they know you. The obvious solution is to go to a decision maker and ask if they agree that your free-time project is not covered by the agreement with the industrial partner or to speak directly with the industrial liaison.

The OP has noted in comments that "The subject of this paper is very much related to my field." And that they are trying to avoid tying the paper to their employment because of reviews mandated by their funding.
Sure, you can claim that all the work was done completely independently of your work. Yet the paper is related to your field, that is, in scope of your work assignment. Therefore, it is not true - at all - that this work is independent.
Possible repercussions of this include losing funding to the institution as well as being fired from the institution. I will not touch on any patent issues, but if you are trying to claim that something you came up with in your field was somehow independent of your employer, well, it won't be a long court case.

And OP will be on the "do not hire" list for both university and industry.

@CaptainEmacs there is no "do not hire" list for "industry". There may be rumors for high level people or in a very small community but we are far from a Vatican Index Of People You Do Not Hire (VIOPYDNH)

@WoJ - sure, there isn’t a literal list, but word does get around. A few calls checking references within the institution will yield direct or indirect information about the issue.

@JonCuster this would not fly in industry, at least in Europe. You are no allowed to call a company to get recommendations about someone. You sure can have a friend who knows a friend but except for very specific hirings nobody does this informal background check because there is not time for that (putting aside the whole illegality of such a check)

Depending on the location and university, how related the paper is to the writer’s field may not even be relevant. I recall an instance perhaps 15 years ago where a researcher in something like biochemistry or medicine had written a novel (on their own time) and was taken to court by their university for royalties because they were employed there at the time and the university claimed ownership of anything written or created during employment. I don't remember the outcome, but it did make it to court (i.e., wasn't thrown out as unenforceable).

@WoJ You are absolutely allowed to check references in Europe – there would be no point in providing them otherwise. There are fairly strict rules about what prospective employers are allowed to ask references, and in some cases the applicant also has the right to a hearing to rebut any potentially damaging information given by a reference, calling a reference is definitely allowed. You’re allowed to not give any references on your CV/job application, of course, but then it wouldn’t be “a few calls checking references” anymore.

@WoJ Depends on the industry. In a large industry, you may disappear in the crowd, indeed. In a small one, especially a competitive one, less so.

@JanusBahsJacquet "You are absolutely allowed to check references in Europe" → I never said that you could not check provided references (though the concept is not common at all), JohnCuster was talking about "making a few calls checking references (...)" which I read as calling people who were not provided by the candidate. This is absolutely forbidden.

@WoJ I think it’s your reading of John’s comment that’s off, then: a reference is by definition provided by the candidate, so in the situation you describe, the calls wouldn’t be checking references but something more like making background checks, which indeed wouldn’t be allowed except in some limited circumstances (e.g., checking criminal records for certain positions). It’s pretty common here for companies to check references in the latter stages of the vetting process, but perhaps not everywhere in Europe.

@JanusBahsJacquet "a reference is by definition provided by the candidate" → in that case I cannot imagine someone providing references to people who would say anything bad. I was asked once to provide references, I sent the contacts of friends who basically explained that I am the next Jesus-turned-IronMan.

@JanusBahsJacquet BTW I think you are in academia, my comment as I mentioned was was about industry

I don't believe it's really possible to have work and non-work hours in intellectual work. You cannot physically make your brain not think about work things when you are otherwise idle (in the shower or laying in bed, say). You cannot physically restrict your brain from thinking about Work2 tasks while doing Work1. Everything you learn doing Work1 has potential to influence Work2, even if the tasks are otherwise orthogonal. You just cannot compartmentalize things in a human brain that way. Therefore the scenario you describe...

You produce, during your free time, i.e. outside of work hours, and without any other university colleague's involvement, a paper with your own funds, so there is no university involvement at any stage during the production of this work

...does not really exist. It's likely that your work contract or whatever agreement you have with your funder recognizes this, as well, and specifically calls out the relationship between your work and your employer, especially where intellectual property is involved.
If you wanted to work on a side project that you were going to keep separate from other work, the time to arrange for a waiver of any other restrictions would be before you've done the actual work. Now that you've actually done it, you can't skip out on the internal review process by the industrial partner just because you don't like it or don't think they will be interested. Companies can be interested in all sorts of intellectual property that does not clearly align with their past interests, that's how they grow, and even if they do not want to use intellectual property directly, if they own it and think it has value then it may be something they want to sell to someone else.
If you don't give them their chance to decide that your project isn't worth any of that to them, they'll have good grounds to be angry with you and have the means to hurt you both by denying future funding and also through legal action. They'll especially come after you if you start trying to make money with it. You would also make your institution angry by upsetting an industrial partner which could cost the institution money in future arrangements.
Don't do it.
You may feel that legal agreements you have or have not signed would give you some protection or that you could prevail in court; if you want to go that direction, you should have a lawyer advise you. However, goodwill and relationships are not built only on legal agreements. You do not need to be found in violation of a specific agreement in court for a company to be displeased and no longer want to provide you funding, for your advisor to find you untrustworthy and no longer want to advise you, for your institution to find you a liability and no longer want to have you as a student.

I am not really planning on commercializing any research output, I am exclusively interested in being able to do research and publish it in time. It seems pretty totalitarian that a company can claim ownership over anything you do in your own free time with your own resources, especially when its far removed from their line of business. The main issue is the time it takes for them to process the paper, it's in on the order of multiple months.

@NewPhD They're paying you a salary, they're not just making these claims out of nothing. You'd be free to not take a salary from them and then use your free time as you wish. Read your contract carefully.

Actually, legally speaking, I have a regular salaried work contract with my university, there is no mention anywhere of the funding source in my employment contract as well. And I personally did not sign anything with the company.  To be even more precise, even if the company were to go bankrupt, that would be immaterial with respect to my employment contract with my university.

@NewPhD What does your work contract with the university say about intellectual property? You say of your other work "I would need to submit it for an internal review process" - this must be based on something (that is, this is not a process that you personally imagined into existence). Even if it's just instructions from your supervisor, that may become something covered under your employment agreement.

My work contract states that I must abide by the university's code, and in this code is a clearly stipulated close against industry partners taking too much time to file protection if need be when the university engages in partnerships with industry. My promotor, who obviously has a vested interested in maintaining a good standing with this industrial partner for future funding, stated that it's the company that has the final word on this matter, and that they can take up to six months if they want to. I asked to see the agreement with the company, but he refused and was defensive about it.

@NewPhD And does it mention outside work at all anywhere in the university's code?

So I just checked the regulations, it states that any intellectual IP generated by the research staff of the university as part of their employment belongs to the university. And in case there is a research agreement with an industrial partner, the said agreement will take precedence regarding the IP generated. I am now not sure to what extent this company has legal ownership over research that is outside the scope of the research project agreement and is on top of this produced outside of my work hours.

Think of it this way: You have a choice between going through the process or gamble that the company or university or both won't take any action. The gamble could go two ways: you either safe 2 months or you are in really serious legal trouble. 2 months is not a lot when it comes to publications. You need to realistically count on being rejected once or twice, then a revise and resubmit, and each of these stages takes at least half a year to a full year. So 2 moths is nothing. So it is a lot of risk for no gain....

@MaartenBuis The main issue is that it's typically on the order of 6 months, not 2 months. This has already led me to miss deadlines for conferences.

Not in academia, so apologies if this question is a bit dumb. But if they left the university, then a year or 2 later started the paper and published it independently, then the university would have 0 claim on his paper, right? What's the difference compared to this scenario? The university research would still have given him the knowledge and experience to work on the independent paper. The university provided no support in either scenario. So why would the university have any claim now? Because it's unclear if he used university resources on his own paper or because they are paying him?

Ok so if the gamble works you may make the deadline for one conference and if the gamble does not work  you are in deep legal trouble. It is still your choice whether you want to make that gamble or not. I know what I would do, but I am not the one who has to make the decision.

@TheEvilMetal This is nothing special to do with academia. When someone pays you a salary for intellectual work, they generally take ownership of all your intellectual production doing that type of work during the time you receive that salary. That's what you're trading the salary for: your intellectual work product. Work done after your salary ends is not covered. Work of a different type is not typically covered. But if you are paid to do research, then research you do is your work that you're being paid a salary for.

You posted many details in the comments that are difficult to make sense of, making it hard to see the forest for the trees here. The edit to your question clarifies things a bit, but again it sounds like a mess of a situation.
Anyway, the specific details don't seem that important. Looking at the big picture, what you are proposing to do is fundamentally dishonest. Your institution pays you a salary to do research. This salary comes with certain strings attached, one of those strings being that you need to go through an approval process to publish your research due to some combination of the area of your research, where the funding and other resources for the research come from, and some weird bureaucratic obstacles.
The dishonesty lies in the fact that despite agreeing to be bound by those limitations (either explicitly, or implicitly by taking the salary) you now want to circumvent them by pretending that your research is not "affiliated" with the university. But that's all it is: a pretense. You are in fact affiliated with your university in every meaningful sense of the word "affiliated" - at least in the context of the work you do in this particular field. (By contrast, if you were to release, say, a rock album, you might be forgiven for publishing it under a different "affiliation"...) This game of "I did this in my free time" is not something that anyone in academia will buy as an honest or reasonable explanation. To be clear, in certain legal contexts related to intellectual property that sort of explanation might protect you (I'm not a lawyer so I can't speak with authority on that, but I have heard of situations where the distinction being work done on your free time versus work time can matter). But for all other purposes, you are likely to upset and heavily damage your relationships with basically everyone involved in employing you or funding your work. Even other unrelated people who notice that you are publishing work under a "double identity" might find this suspicious and shady, and form a negative opinion of you, whether or not they learn the details of why you acted the way you did.
The bottom line is, I understand that you are frustrated by what you perceive as misguided and heavy-handed bureaucracy standing in your way of just doing and publishing good, honest research. I sympathize, and I wish you luck in finding a way forward, but your current proposed solution is simply not an appropriate way to address this issue.

Does this mean any research you do as a hobby in your free time belongs to a company that signed an agreement with your university even if the research themes are far apart? The salary I am receiving pays for a research project with a clearly defined line of research. I do perform the requested research and go through the 6 month bureaucratic process in order to publish it. So I think I am fulfilling my contractual obligation as an employee. Why would this company then extend its scope to work I do in my free time that is not even related to the theme of the research they signed?

@NewPhD my answer is not meant to be interpreted as legal advice. I was commenting on what I perceive as the duplicity of your idea of pretending that research that is “very much related to your field” (your own words) is done as a “hobby” and “on your free time”, and how that duplicity is likely to affect your professional relationships, not on any legal aspects. If you want advice on fulfilling your contractual obligations, talk to a lawyer.

I think the least terrible thing that can happen to you is that you will not able to renew your industry funding.  For all the other things that could go wrong, you will need to consult an intellectual property lawyer or the people who gave you this funding.

I think this is mostly a legal question. You need to check your employment contract and the rules of your institution. You probably need to contact a lawyer to be sure.
Generally, I do not think it is completely hopeless (I once knew a professor who convinced the university that a patent he was involved in does not belong to the university because it was not related to his research), but difficult.

For most people and most situations that would be fine. There are, however, exceptions where your contract specifies that all IP belongs to the institution. So, check to see if you have contractural obligations. This occurs mostly, but not exclusively, in industry.
The idea is that time and specific collaboration aren't the only considerations if you learn things while working that are considered proprietary. That is unlikely for university faculty unless they are involved in some "spooky" stuff with confidentially requirements generally.
However, as mentioned in comments, there is little downside to using your university affiliation unless, there are, again, contractual obligations that arise if you do so.
As to the patent question, make sure you understand patent law where you intend to file. The situation in the US has become a bit weird recently with the notion of "first to file". You may have to file before you make anything known about your "invention". For patent questions, see a lawyer - a good one.
And, for patentable "inventions", it is actually more likely that a research university would claim all such IP of its employees in employment contracts. This has been discussed in other questions here. Many, but not all, consider this to be a good thing as patent filing can be expensive. The defense of patents can be even more expensive. The university would absorb these costs and will usually share any proceeds with the "inventor".

The broad claims to IP happen at universities as well.  Have a look at Purdue's IP policy.  They ask "Is the IP entirely unrelated to your scope of employment or field of research at the University?" and do not talk about work hours.  https://www.purdue.edu/research/oevprp/regulatory-affairs/intellectual-property-faq.php

@TerryLoring, I've edited to clarify my meaning. I only claim it is more common in industry.

I also work as a university researcher. What you are suggesting may be illegal and may have consequences for you and you department or it may not. I don't think strangers on the internet can tell you what you can or cannot do. Judges interpret the law and you are a grown up so should be able to consider the morality yourself, but here are some pointers to questions that I might ask myself in your situation.
Is the work you are have done related to your work at the university? Did you use any university owned equipment in producing the work, including writing up the paper? Did you reference any papers to which the university has a paid subscription. Is there a clause in your contact about intellectual property? If the answer to any of these questions is yes, then you might find that the university owns the copyright to the paper you have written and if this was the case you may not legally be allowed to publish it.
Is there possible reputational harm to the university or the industrial partner? There is clearly a reason why the university has chosen to run all papers in this field via its industrial partner, even if you don't know it. There may be a contract in place where the industrial partner is paying money to get a first look at these papers and exploit any IP. If you publish without permission the university could be seen to be in breach of contract with its industrial partner. The consequences of this could range from nothing, to you getting a telling of to who knows what more serious things.
Is there some emotional driver here? Maybe you are angry with your department for something (perhaps the delay in the publishing process, perhaps something else). Perhaps you are stressing over the need to get this paper published fast so it can go on your CV for job hunting. Perhaps you don't agree with the links with the industrial partner. Perhaps there is some other issue between the university and you. Perhaps this is work that you don't want to tell your supervisor you have done.
So in the end it might be that you are allowed to do it, but you still anger your university or perhaps you are not allowed to do it, but nobody notices or cares anyway. It's for you to take that risk if you see fit.
Whatever the situation, my best advice would be to take a step back, consider that you may not have the full picture of the reason for the departmental policy, consider what the consequences might be for you and others, consider who you might upset and the human impact of your actions, decide if you care about those consequences and the upset you could cause. Then act accordingly and live with whatever those consequences turn out to be.

Perhaps, but when I find myself wanting to go against policy, it's usually because I've messed something up, I'm stressed or I want to make a point. These are actually all emotional reactions more than anything else.

The decision about whether the sponsoring organisation could exert a hold on his intellectual property is not the OPs decision to make. It was made by someone else significantly higher up the organisation. So I would say this isn't a valid concern. If the university has a claim on the IP of the work then they are absolutely entitled to have a policy on how this is utilised. If what the OP says is correct - that the work is not relevant to the body, then the only reason to avoid the internal review is speed and it is likely that this need for speed is purely personal.

I absolutely have concern about natural justice, but the reality might be that, whether the OP likes it or not, his university owns the IP to this work done in his spare time. My contract contains a clause saying that any IP from any work I do in the field related to my department is owned by my university regardless of whether it is done in work time or my time. This is a much broader field than just my current project. But the harm may (or may not) be broader than IP infringement. It may upset people who have some say over the OP's future employment

And, this depends on the country, but here in the UK, any IP generated during the course of employment belongs by default to the employer.

As many others have noted this is mainly a legal problem so the OP should seek professional advice.
I'm not a lawyer and we don't have access to all the documents, contracts, etc, but there might be yet another solution, which the OP should investigate, i.e. publishing with the university affiliation, but without cooperation with the industry partner.
Usually, research staff in a university can be funded from multiple sources. There can be several grants from funding agencies and/or industry. Often, there is also the basic salary, which is not sponsored by any specific grant. When you publish a paper you need to disclose the funding source for each particular author. To my understanding, if you publish a paper under your university's affiliation, but do not mention the industry funding, you're not bound by the rules of the grant. Heck, you might concurrently work for a different project on the same university, which is funded from somewhere else.
I'd say that if you were hired by the university before the cooperation with the industry partner started, and in the mean time you didn't sign any new contracts, then you should be able to publish in the exactly same way as before the cooperation started (without mentioning the extra funding). On the other hand if you were hired in a lab which is completely funded by the industry partner, and always has been, that's a different story. The devil lies in the details. You should consult your specific legal situation with some legal experts on the university and/or independent of the university.
The main question is: are you allowed to work on other projects on your university? Like funded by a different company, funded by a government agency, or funded internally by the university itself.
